# How do I properly set up PHPMailer with Gmail SMTP Servers?

Tags: php, email

I have a form that basically has 3 radio buttons that will let you pick a staff member you want to get in contact with. The form requires a name, email and message. I cannot find where it tells me what the error is. I have debugging on but do not know where the error is coming from.

My goal is to have it so that the person they select will be emailed and when the email is sent it will be redirected to a page that has the correct staff members info on it. However for the life of me I cannot get this to work. I believe everything works correct but when I inserted the code that I found on SO to connect to the SMTP servers and email the contact form input my formProcess.php breaks.

**EDIT:** With the help of some of you here I have found the solution to 2 of the errors I am getting. However now that I have fixed these errors I am getting a different error. I am now receiving this:

*2015-12-23 04:42:59    SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Cannot allocate memory (12) 2015-12-23 04:42:59    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting 2015-12-23 04:42:59  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Cannot allocate memory (12) 2015-12-23 04:42:59    SMTP connect() failed. [https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting_)*

*Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/contact/phpmailer/class.smtp.php:234) in /www/contact/formProcess.php on line 80*

**EDIT 2:** I have uploaded it to my hosted server. It has solved the error mentioned above. I now have an issue with the password failing, even though I have signed in using the password I am using in the code. Instead of copy/pasting the error message you can see it live on [my site](http://www.Antidote89.com) for yourself.

**EDIT 3:** I just noticed that there is an email from Gmail that says "Someone tried to sign in to your Google Account from an app that doesn't meet standard security standards." This can't be a coincidence can it? Is this why I cannot connect? and if so what can I do to meet security standards?

**EDIT 4:** I have now got everything working fine except for 2 things. 1, for some reason it is sending the emails twice. I am not sure why but I feel like I can figure it out. The real issue I am having now is that I now want to include Googles reCAPTCHA to my form as well. Everything works fine until I added this bit of code that I thought would verify if the reCAPTCHA was successful and if it wasn't just add an error to my code, but after I entered the code below to do that my code breaks.

```
$curl = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
       'secret'=>'Well it says secret for a reason!',
       'response'=> $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
    ]
]);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

if (!$response->success){
    $errors[] = 'There was a problem with reCAPTCHA, please try again.';
};
```

And bellow is all code that processes the form.

```
<?php

session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors = [];
$toWho ='';

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'],     $_POST['who'])){

$fields = [
  'name' => $_POST['name'],  
  'email' => $_POST['email'],  
  'message' => $_POST['message'],
  'who' => $_POST['who']
];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)) {
        $errors[] ='The ' .$field. ' field is required.';
    }
}

    if ($fields['who'] ==  "staff1") {
    $toWho = 'staff1@domain.com';
} else if ($fields['who'] == "staff2")  {
    $toWho = 'staff2@domain.com';
} else {
    $toWho = 'staff3@domain.com';
}






$curl = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
       'secret'=>'Well it says secret for a reason!',
       'response'=> $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
    ]
]);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

if (!$response->success){
    $errors[] = 'There was a problem with reCAPTCHA, please try again.';
};









if(empty($errors)) {

    $mail = new PHPMailer;



    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->smtpSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

//        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;

    $mail->Host = 'mailen3.cloudsector.net';

    $mail->From = "No-reply@domain.com";
    $mail->Username = 'No-Reply@domain.com';
    $mail->Password = 'PAsswoRD';

    $mail->SetFrom("No-reply@domain.com", "No Reply" );
    $mail->AddReplyTo($fields['email'], $fields['name']);
    $mail->AddAddress($toWho, $fields['who']);

    $mail->Subject    = $fields['name'] . ' wants to talk!';
    $mail->Body       = 'From: ' .$fields['name']. ' (' .$fields['email']. ') ' .$fields['message']. ;




    $mail->send();


    if($mail->send()) {
        header('Location: ../../' .$fields['who']. 'thanks.php');
        die();
    }else {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry! Something went wrong and your message could not be sent. Please try again ';
    }


}


} else {
     $errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
 }

 $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
 $_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

 header('Location: index.php');
 ?>
```

Comment: Well what exactly are the errors? Put `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script.

Comment: I get 2 errors. the first one saying **"Use of undefined constant staff1 - assume 'staff1' in /www/contact/formProcess.php on line 27"**. and **Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailerAutoload' not found in /www/contact/formProcess.php on line 38**

Comment: It's not a coincidence, you have to log into your google account and change some security settings. This link should help: http://www.wpsitecare.com/gmail-smtp-settings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try displaying errors by adding the following code at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

If you're getting a server error 500, Try commenting out small blocks of code until the script works. That way you can identify the problem.

Comment: I get 2 errors. the first one saying "Use of undefined constant staff1 - assume 'staff1' in /www/contact/formProcess.php on line 27". and Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailerAutoload' not found in /www/contact/formProcess.php on line 38

Comment: Change `if ($fields['who'] ==  staff1) {` to `if ($fields['who'] ==  "staff1") {`. And there appears to be a problem in the file `PHPMailerAutoload.php`. Verify that it contains a class definition for PHPMailerAutoload.

Comment: The second error is due to `$mail = new phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload;` is meant to be `$mail = new PHPMailer;`

Comment: @matt Thank you both. I have fixed the current problems and now have new ones. I have updated my post to reflect the new issues I am having.

Comment: @cantelope Thank you both. I have fixed the current problems and now have new ones. I have updated my post to reflect the new issues I am having.

Comment: It looks like your new errors are related to GoDaddy's server settings. The script you're using is trying to run an external program which is prohibited. You might want to move your website to a VPS for more control of the server.

Comment: @cantelope I would love to, but this is just not an option for me. Should I just go around GoDaddy and use something like Gmail?

Comment: @cantelope I have tested it out using the Gmail settings and I still receive the same error. I am currently doing this on my local machine and it is not live. I am using MAMP running it on localhost.

Comment: Well the error "cannot allocate memory" would seem to indicate there is a memory problem on your Apple. Some troubleshooting steps can be found [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting). You could also try running the script on a different machine, if possible.

Comment: @cantelope It was something wrong with either my MAMP config or my laptop  as you suggested. Now I am getting a new error. I updated the code above and linked to where you can see it live. I have the correct email/password as I have logged in and out several times on my browser. For some reason however phpmailer or my site/host doesn't want to connect to my server. I am also no longer on GoDaddy.

Comment: If you're on GoDaddy shared hosting, you cannot use Gmail. You have to use their stupid slow relay servers.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I am no longer with GoDaddy. I moved hosts yesterday to a new host because of the growing frustration with all of their ways of doing things. I am now being told that the password does not work even though when I enter it in the browser I am able to sigh in fine.